# Appcelerator Studio does not recognize xcode

Tags: xcode, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I have been working on cross platform mobile app. I have develop the app its working on windows with android. Now I want to test it on iPhone. I have install the mac os x yosemite on virtual box. I have install the xcode 6.4 and also have create test app, its working. I have installed the **Appcelerator Studio but it don't run the code in iPhone simulator**. It says no required sdk installed. I have also try the `xcode-select` command. Here are xcode and Appcelerator Studio screenshot from my vm.

[image: Appcelerator Studio ios sdk not found issue]

[image: Appcelerator Studio]

[image: Xcode 6.4]

Comment: Check your installed Node , titanium SDK and CLI version. I think there is some mismatch in the configuration.

Comment: How did you install the Xcode - from App store or using dmg file?

Comment: @Anand Using dmg file, which I have download from apple developer site

Comment: Can you try installing it from App Store. I faced such issue once and got fixed when I did the same

Comment: Did you solve this? I am facing the same issue, tried both installing from App Store or from a plain DMG-file.

Answer (score 3):

To identify the problem,

1.Check whether the Xcode is installed in the system?

2.Is Xcode identified by Appcelerator CLI. Run the following command to see whether it's detected?

```
$ appc ti info -t ios
Appcelerator Command-Line Interface, version 5.4.0
Copyright (c) 2014-2016, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

Xcode
  7.1 (build 7B60) - Xcode default
    Install Location          = /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer
    iOS SDKs                  = 9.1
    iOS Simulators            = 9.1, 8.4
    Watch SDKs                = 2.0
    Watch Simulators          = 2.0
    Supported by TiSDK 5.2.0.v20151009204435 = yes
    Teams                     = none
```

3. If it's not shown, Run `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app`
4. Still not listed, make sure you have right version version of node,appc CLI and SDK.
5. If it's detected by CLI but not in the studio, open studio preferences.

   Studio -> Platforms -> iOS -> Click on 'Refresh'

Comment: Thanks @kondal this helped.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try:
`XCode > Preferences > Locations > Command Line Tools` => Select desired version of Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Close studio and Install node https://nodejs.org/en/download/. Reopen studio and try Studio -> Platforms -> iOS -> Click on 'Refresh'